# What to call a system that gives users customized access to data?

Tags: data, system

What would be the proper way to describe a system whose sole purpose it is to give users access to large amounts of data in a structured way according to their own criteria?

Like say for example someone, for whatever reason, wanted to build a system that gave the user access to every permutation of the integers 0-9. But if the user wanted to narrow down the results by specifying only sets containing four integers should be returned, or that they want all permutations that don't include the numbers 7 of 3, or some other criteria.

What would you call such a system (or program)? An “information system”? Or a “data access framework”? Or something else...?

Comment: In general terms, a system that provides results that can be narrowed down using criteria suggests a *database system.*  The operation so described is called a "query." But maybe you just want generated data, as you stated, in which case I would just call it "code."  Or, as Doc Brown suggests in his answer below, simply give it a name that is reminiscent of what it does or what kind of data it returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A direct answer to this question is definitely too opinionated to make sense, but I think the question can be read as "how to find a descriptive name" for such a system, not "tell me a name", and that is something I think I can answer.

A descriptive name for a system should ideally reflect its main use case, in terms of the business or domain (assumed the name is not for marketing purposes).

Your example looks way too contrived to demonstrate this, at a first glance, but I can imagine an artificial domain where those "permutations of the integers" could make sense: let's say those numbers are useful in some kind of lottery. Then if you are looking for a descriptive name, it should have the term "lottery" in it. And depending on the capabilities of the system, I would describe it as something like a

- lottery number generator
- lottery query program
- lottery information system
- lottery data management system

or whatever fits best to the actual use cases supported by the program.

Or, lets say those numbers are phone numbers - then replace "lottery" by "phone number". Or, lets says those numbers are cryptographics keys - I think you get the idea.

So think for yourself: what **kind of data** is you system managing or providing? Which **business** or **domain** is involved, or what is the **purpose** for managing or providing the data? That should guide you in finding a good name. Just don't give it a name like "data access framework", that's quite the opposite of being descriptive.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I was looking for a title that describes the WAY that the data is handled by the system. Like a "sorting algorithm" is called that because of what it does. In your reflection on my example, calling the resulting numbers lottery numbers or phone numbers doesn't change how the system works, how it performs its function. It still works the same way no matter how you use the output. Perhaps I'm over thinking this. I'm working on requirements documentation now and just searching for the right language.